# else statement wont work

Tags: python

I am new to Python and I am trying to get the below code to work but the else statement isn't working:

```
print("What's your name?")
my_name = input()


if my_name == "Simon" or "simon":
    print("Hello, Simon!")
else:
    print("Hello, stranger!")
```

Comment: See [“or” conditional in Python troubles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17375793/or-conditional-in-python-troubles)

Answer (score 1):

You need to do separate comparisons with each string, and connect them with `or` like this

```
if my_name == "Simon" or my_name == "simon":
```

Full Code

```
print("What's your name?")
my_name = input()

if my_name == "Simon" or my_name == "simon":
    print("Hello, Simon!")
else:
    print("Hello, stranger!")
```

Sample Output

```
wolf@linux:~$ py script.py 
What's your name?
hey
hey
Hello, stranger!
wolf@linux:~$ 
wolf@linux:~$ 
wolf@linux:~$ py script.py 
What's your name?
simon
simon
Hello, Simon!
wolf@linux:~$
```

Hope this helps.